# MATLAB - Summing values after reading their position from another matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have an array that consists of some elements (A) and I want to take the nth element and sum it with a number of elements that follow it, and I have a matrix that gives me the position of each of the elements from which I should start summing (B).

For example I have

```
A = [2 3 4 5 6 3 5 7 3 7 3 7 4 7 3 6 2 6 3 8 4 8 4 8 5 8 3]
```

And I have

```
B = [8 12 15]
```

So I would want to sum the value at position B(1,1) which is 8, therefore A(1,8) with the next 4 elements in the matrix

```
C(1,1) = 7 + 3 + 7 + 3
C(1,2) = 7 + 4 + 7 + 3
C(1,3) = 3 + 6 + 2 + 6
```

Comment: `C = sum(A(B(1):B(2)-1))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a big fun to use `bsxfun`:

```
idx = bsxfun( @plus, B, (0:3)' ); %//' indices of A to be summed together
C = sum( A(idx), 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

What I undersdtand from you question is that you want to calculate a matrix C, you only shown an example for calculating C(1,1). C(1,2) will be like,

C(1,2) =  7 + 4 + 7 + 3 + 6 + 2 + 6 + 3 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 5 + 8 + 3 = 86

If I'm right my answer is like this

```
for i = 1:n
   C(i) = 0;
   for j = B(i):m
      C(i) += A(j);
   end
end
```

where

n = B's length (2 in your example)

m = 4 (because you want to add next **4** elements in the matrix)